# compare values in a dictionary and do stuff with each based on value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a CSV with a bunch of columns. I only want three of the columns. 
I imported this into my python script and turned the three columns into three lists

Then added each list to a dictionary. List 1 being the keys and the other lists being the two values. (maybe theres a better way to do this?)

```
key is a transaction id
value1 is a filename
value2 is a date
```

In the end what  want is this:

1. run through the dict and find all duplicate file names (there will be multiple sets of duplicates)
2. for each set of the duplicate filenames, find the one id(key) that has the latest(most recent) date value (if time and date are the same, then highest id(key))
3. print key of the latest date (all i need is the id)
4. for each of the other duplicates print "this is a duplicate"+ (key) (again just need the id of each)

I want to repeat that for all keys until i essentially get the ids(keys) of only the latest items in the list. There could be 5 duplicate filenames of filename x and 100 dupes for filename y and 30 for filename t and so on.

I'm using an API to actually move data, which is why I need to get the latest and move that ID to "x" and all duplicates to "y" in this external system.

Here's what I have in terms of building the dict (assuming its building in the correct order), but I don't really know where to go from here:

```
import csv

def readcsv(filename, column):
    file = open(filename, "rU")
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=",")
    list = []
    for row in reader:
         list.append(row[(column)])
    file.close()
    return list

def makeDict(id, fileName, detDate):
        iList = {z[0]:list(z[1:]) for z in zip((id),(fileName),(detDate))}
        return (iList)

id = (readcsv("jul.csv", 2))
fileName = (readcsv("jul.csv", 1))
detDate = (readcsv("jul.csv", 0))

mainDict = makeDict((id), (fileName), (detDate))
```

sample data (extracted the columns into a simpler sheet for testing)

```
Date    fileURL ID
7/24/2018 16:04 https://localhost/file1.docx    2599302
7/24/2018 16:03 https://localhost/file3.docx    2349302
7/24/2018 16:01 https://localhost/file1.docx    2599302
7/24/2018 16:04 https://localhost/fil232.xml    2599303
7/24/2018 16:03 https://localhost/file1.docx    2349333
7/24/2018 16:01 https://localhost/file3.docx    2529374
```

**UPDATE:**
Using the answer from below, this is what I ended up with that made it work:

```
import csv

def readcsv(filename, column):
    file = open(filename, "rU")
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=",")
    list = []
    for row in reader:
         list.append(row[(column)])
    file.close()
    return list

def makeDict(id, fileName, detDate):
        iList = {z[0]:list(z[1:]) for z in zip((id),(fileName),(detDate))}
        return (iList)


## Group Keys by like file names ##
def groupKeys(mainDict):
    same_filename = {}
    for key, line in (mainDict).items():
     name, date = line
     if name not in same_filename:
       same_filename[name] = [key]
     else:
       same_filename[name].append( key )
    return(same_filename)



########################################### Get latest ID ##################
def getLatestID(same_filename, mainDict):
## for each file
    for k in (same_filename.keys()):
     curDate = 0
     curID = 0
 ## get each id value (aka matching ids holding same file)
     for v in (same_filename.get((k))):
      moveDupeList.append(v)   ## add to a list of dupes 

  ## if current id's date is equal to the highest found so far - note:date already set since its same
      if ((mainDict.get((v)))[1]) == (curDate):

    ## check which id is highest and set curId if new high found
       if (v) > (curId):
        curId = (v)

    ## else if date of current is greater than greatest found so far set new highest date and id
      elif ((mainDict.get((v)))[1]) > (curDate):
       curDate = ((mainDict.get((v)))[1])
       curId = (v)
     if (curId) in moveDupeList:
      moveDupeList.remove((curId))   #remove latest from dupe list
     moveProperList.append((curId))  #add latest to proper list
########################################### Get latest ID ##################


id = (readcsv("jul.csv", 2))
fileName = (readcsv("jul.csv", 1))
detDate = (readcsv("jul.csv", 0))

mainDict = makeDict((id), (fileName), (detDate))
same_filename = (groupKeys(mainDict))
getLatestID((same_filename), (mainDict))
```

Comment: Is using `pandas` an option? You'd be able to do that entire calculation with an initial sort and then a `groupby`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A starting point could be to build another dictionary giving for each filename the list of all corresponding key(id):

```
data = {2349302: ['7/24/2018 16:03', 'https://localhost/file3.docx'],
 2349333: ['7/24/2018 16:03', 'https://localhost/file1.docx'],
 2529374: ['7/24/2018 16:01', 'https://localhost/file3.docx'],
 2599302: ['7/24/2018 16:01', 'https://localhost/file1.docx'],
 2599303: ['7/24/2018 16:04', 'https://localhost/fil232.xml']}

similar_filename = {}
for key, line in data.items():
    date, name = line
    if name not in similar_filename:
        similar_filename[name] = [key]
    else:
        similar_filename[name].append( key )


similar_filename
>>> {'https://localhost/fil232.xml': [2599303],
 'https://localhost/file1.docx': [2599302, 2349333],
 'https://localhost/file3.docx': [2529374, 2349302]}
```

This is your first point.

Comment: full solution in my original post